# Recommend any Molecular lab LIMS (Laboratory Information Management System)

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, lab-techniques

We are looking to develop or customize a LIMS for our molecular lab. Do you know of a LIMS that you've used in a molecular lab before, or one that could be used.

Thanks for the help

(Edit)
Some of the attributes we'd like to store include:
    Patient information (Name, demographics, test ordered)
    Sample information (Accession #, Case ID, sample type (blood,bone, etc.) )
    Test information (Kit used, Kit lot #, associated expiration date)
Ideally this is Software as a Service so its usable on multiple operating systems.

Comment: What are your precise requirements? online/offline ? Lab notebook or it should handle inventories also? Linux or MS or cross platform?

Comment: We use Quartzy to manage all of our lab supplies and reagents. As far as I know though, this does not allow you to also store things like patient records, or lab notebooks.

Comment: What kind of management? Orders? Stocks ??

Comment: I just added some additional info. Hope this helps clarify